# Subject verb object word order

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is wrong with the following question in relation to subject verb object word order?

> Me, I dont like traveling by bus

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. It's what we call a left-dislocation.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, but "I" doesn't need an antecedent, surely?

Comment: I'd punctuate it differently. "[You're asking]Me? I don't like traveling by bus"

Comment: @BillJ Yes, it's not a normal left-dislocation in that respect. It feels a bit like a topicalisation doesn't it? (although it isn't one, of course)

Comment: Context is most, there. If I ask you what you think about public transport, what would be odd about "Me? I dont like traveling by bus", please?